# Ensuring that Array Takes Entire Row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my CSS, and I have a row that can show up to three courses per row.  The problem I have is that when there is only one or two courses for a row, the footer (which is the content below the courses) moves up(please see my image below to see an example).  How do I ensure that the content below the courses doesn't move up, even when there is only 1 or 2 courses?

Here's the code in my view:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= course.name %>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [complete html and css](https://jsfiddle.net/yellowreign/xvnt8ebL/).

This is an [example page.](https://jsfiddle.net/yellowreign/xvnt8ebL/embedded/result/)

[image]

Comment: You need to post an actual working example that demonstrates your problem: post your HTML output as well as any CSS in a Snippet. The Ruby by itself isn't that helpful. [mcve]

Comment: Can't you just add your footer content to a new row ?

Comment: Thanks @vanburen, I added an example and the full HTML and CSS.

Comment: @DavidDomain, thanks for the suggestion.  I tried, but unfortunately, it didn't work to just put the footer in a row.

Comment: @yellowreign just give your footer clear:both;

Comment: @localZero I realized that it was my pagination element, not footer that was getting moved up.  However, when I added `clear:both;` to `.pagination` in the css file, the problem remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your .pagination class inside a div and then add `clear: both` to your css.

Comment: I ended up putting my pagination in between a container div class.  `<div class="container">
    <%= will_paginate @courses %>
  </div>`